# Showing dynamically content in an efficient way, without using different template for every situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Best explained with an example:

Lets say I have many records, which I want to display in an html table.
The columns which are shown are chosen before hand.

In this case,

**user name** (if `@options[:user_name]`)

**user email** (if `@options[:user_email]`)

**sms phone** (if `@options[:user_email]`)

**add new task** (only if admin is not spectator)

Point is there are many different dynamic variables which decides which columns to show- Now this isn't a problem for the table header `thead` but It is a waste to ask the same questions and getting the same answers for  **every record (user)**- there must be a better way.

I know I need to display the `user_name`, I don't want to ask if I need to for every user. But I can't make a different template for every combination of options etc'.

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <%= content_tag :td, 'User Name' if @options[:user_name] %>
            <%= content_tag :td, 'User Email' if @options[:user_email] %>
            <%= content_tag :td, 'Sms Phone' if @site.include_phone? %>
            <% if admin? %>
              <th>Actions</th>
            <% end %>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% @many_users.each.with_index(1) do |user, index| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= index %>. </td>
              <%= content_tag :td, user.name if @options[:user_name] %>
              <%= content_tag :td, user.get_email_from_db(@options[:admin]) if @options[:user_name] %>
              <%= content_tag :td, @site.get_phone(user) if @site.include_phone? %>

              <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to new_task_path(user_id: user.id) do %>new task<% end unless admin_is_spectator? %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

To summarize: How do I avoid asking the same `ifs questions` for which I know the answer before hand for every record?